# How can I call an external file from .asm file

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

I saw one other post from 4 years ago, with the same question but it used NASM and I couldn't understand it at all. I have a .py file, that's in the same folder as my assembly file. I need to change that to an .exe , to be able to call it from the .asm , or so I was told. I cant find how to call it though. I saw int 21h/ah=4Bh but did not understand it at all. I need it to just run once and go back, like a procedure. How is this done?

TLDR-Using Dosbox and Tasm, How can I call an external program into mine, to run and then have the original file continue running.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using DOS? I haven't checked but my guess is you'd have a hard time finding a python environment for DOS.

Comment: im learning in school, its what i was taught, we have to use it for our final project...

Comment: And they told you to run python in DOS? Have they given you a python executable for DOS?

Comment: It's our final project, our teacher said do whatever you want, and I asked about a real time stock price thing and asked if it's possible, he said to use python or php and call it through assembly since it is an assembly class... I wasn't given anything special for dos or anything

Comment: That sounds like poor advice from your teacher.  I'd think you'd end up doing most of the work writing Python, and basically just end up with an asm program that runs Python and then prints the contents of a file to the screen, in a loop.  i.e. not very interesting asm unless you make the API complex on purpose.  But if you want it to work inside DOSBOX, you'll need a version of Python that can run inside DOSBOX and access the Internet.  (Unlike if you had 32-bit Windows where a 16-bit DOS executable can run under Windows with NTVDM, and could launch a regular 32-bit Python interpreter.)

Comment: Lol, you're right btw, I'm making it alot longer in the asm on purpose, and thanks!

Comment: If you can do internet access from inside DOSBOX, maybe do that directly from asm?  If you have a TCP library, anyway.  This would be so much easier if you were using normal 32-bit or 64-bit assembly running directly under a modern OS, so you could use normal TCP sockets, or even an HTTP library. Hmm, maybe you could write a relay program in python that runs outside DOSBOX, and have it look for files in a directory. Then your asm makes requests by writing to files and moving them into a directory, and looking for the result in another directory. (create then move avoids reading a partial file)